# How to change the progressbar's color in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, progress-bar

the default color of the progressbar is blue(maybe),how to change the color of the progressbar?or even change the bkcolor of the mfc's controls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you are working with a `CProgressCtrl` named `progressBarCtrl`, have a try with:

```
COLORREF clrBar = RGB(0, 0, 0); // the bar color
progressBarCtrl.SendMessage(PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, (LPARAM) clrBar);
```

for background:

```
COLORREF clrBg = RGB(255, 255, 255); // the background color
progressBarCtrl.SendMessage(PBM_SETBKCOLOR, 0, (LPARAM) clrBg);
```

[PMB_SETBARCOLOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760838.aspx) and [PBM_SETBKCOLOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760840.aspx) are Windows messages for changing the color settings of progress bar controls.

By the way, there is a method [`SetBkColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4syt4ss.aspx) for `CProgressCtrl` which can be used for background color.