# How to change progressbar color

Tags: c++, mfc, progress-bar

I use Visual studio 2012, MFC.
I have a progressbar I want to change its color during runtime.
I have tried:
   1. SetBarColor
   2. SendMessage(PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, (LPARAM) clrBar)

but both did not change the progress color (it is still green....)

Any solution?
Ido

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but did you notice the remark: `When visual styles are enabled, this message has no effect.`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Can you post some code for figure out what is happening

Comment: Use answer given in flowing post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235314/how-to-change-the-progressbars-color-in-mfc

Comment: @KristerAndersson I read it but I have not idea what MSDN means by "visual styles are enabled...."?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard tell exactly what is going on without code but I a possible solution would just be to redraw the bar at that given with another color.